# TypeScript - outDir to a folder of another project

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a solution that contains 2 projects (not 2 folders in a project):

- **Core**: storing TS code
- **CrmPackage**: storing JS code that can be deployed to the server

**What I want**: the output folder should be distributed in the **CrmPackage** project as following

- Solution

  - Core

    - TS

      - Account

        - account.ts
    - tsconfig.json
  - CrmPackage

    - JS

      - Account

        - account.js

**What I have tried**: setting the `"outDir" = "../CrmPackage/JS"` in tsconfig.json, but it creates the folder `CrmPackage/JS` directly in the Core project.

Comment: In any case, check that the rootDir compiler option points to your src directory and not to the parent directory, because the structure under the rootDir is what is mirrored under the outDir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as following:

**Solution 1**:

1. Set tsconfig.json to put all output js files into folder 'JS' in Core project: `"outDir": "JS"`
2. Use Post-build actions in Visual Studio to copy the all folders & subfolders & files from 'JS' folder (in Core project) to 'WebResources' folder (in CrmPackage project):
   `xcopy "$(ProjectDir)JS\*.*" "$(SolutionDir)CrmPackage\WebResources" /Y /I /E`

**Solution 2**:

1. Simply use webpack to build and bundle typescript into the destination project